# unable to remove white blank space on left hand side when scrolled from right to left

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am working on angularjs google charts. I want to show the horizontal scrollbar for the chart and it should be by default scrolled from right to left.

Sample demo http://jsfiddle.net/uzbozqz4/

To make scrollbar by default scroll from right to left, i have used the following css code defined in style attribute below:

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="margin-left:0;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;direction:rtl;left:0;top:0;height: 500px;"></div>
```

`direction:rtl` makes scrollbar scroll from right to left which is required, but the issue is i can see **lot of white space at the left hand side when scrolled from right to left**. I tried using left-padding:0px; but still it shows whitespace. Any suggestions on how to remove extra white space on left hand side when scrolled from right to left?

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},

        };
   var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="margin-left:0;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;direction:rtl;left:0;top:0;height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

PS: When i remove `direction:rtl` extra blank space is not shown, but as per my requirement i need to use it to make horizontal scrollbar scrolled from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the divs has:

```
div {
  left: -1000px
}
```

It can be identified and targetted by its `aria-label`:

```
div[aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart."] {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuockLyb/1/)

Comment: But then scrollbar is missing, after certain bars are shown, i want the scrollbar so that users can scroll and view the bars from right to left.@ovokuro

Comment: Which scrollbar is missing? The horizontal scrollbar is still visible for me when I resize the screen

Comment: Working demo before applying css code to scroll from right to left :tooltip on mouseover is shown as expected
https://plnkr.co/edit/SwEUeCN8IoT0JN5RrvUx?p=preview
Demo after applying css code to scroll from right to left : Issue is tooltip on mouseover on the bar is not shown as expected
https://plnkr.co/edit/INfdkrotpyo87fpdN9rR?p=preview . After applying the css code as suggested, tooltip on mouseover on bar is not working, any suggestions? @ovokuro